# What's better for RDP - PPTP VPN or Port Forwarding?

Tags: security, remote-desktop, port-forwarding, pptp

I need to be able to connect to a computer via RDP from a tablet, over the Internet.

I was unable to make the tablet connect to a IPSec or L2TP VPN - the only thing that worked was PPTP.

Is PPTP secure enough? Does it have vulnerabilities so that enabling it on the router would expose my internal network? Would it be better to just set up port forwarding on the router for RDP?

Comment: Try here for a start: [Wikipedia: Point-to-Point Tunneling Protocol: Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Tunneling_Protocol#Security).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your client has a static IP address and you trust that only you will ever use that address, then you could poke a hole in the firewall and connect directly with RDP.

If you can't predict your client's address, use a VPN instead.  PPTP can be secure if implemented correctly, but can be problematic if you want to have more than one connection from or to a single IP address.

Comment: The client will have a dynamic IP; it will not be an always-on VPN (for that I'm already using IPSec VPN between routers)

Comment: You wrote "PPTP can be secure if implemented correctly" - what about PPTP in Windows 7, is it safe?